# docker exec with standard output logged in a file inside the docker container

Tags: linux, docker, cron

I am currently running a cronjob from a host machine (Linux Redhat) executing a script in a docker container. The problem I have is that when I redirect the standard output to a file with path inside the docker container, the cronjob threw an exception basically saying that the path of the log file cannot be found. But if I change the output log file path to be a path that is on the host machine, it works fine.

Below does not work

```
0 9 * * 1-5 sudo docker exec -i /path/in/docker/container/script.sh > /path/in/docker/container/script.shout
```

But this one works

```
0 9 * * 1-5 sudo docker exec -i /path/in/docker/container/script.sh > /path/in/host/script.shout
```

How do I get the first cronjob working so I can have the output file in the docker container using the path in the docker container?

I don't want to run the cronjob as `root` and that's why I need `sudo` before `docker exec`. Please note, only `root` has access to the `docker volume` path in the host machine, which is why I can't use the docker volume path either.

Comment: both the answers from work but solution from @VonC was chosen because it is cleaner (no need to add anything on the cronjob line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather try and path the redirection path as a *parameter* to the script (so remove the '`>`'), and make the script itself redirect its output to that parameter file.

Since the script is executed in a docker container, it would see that path (as opposed to the cron job, which sees by default host paths)

Comment: is it by adding `exec > /path/to/output_file/in/docker_container 2>&1` in the end of my `.sh` script?

Comment: @user7799677 yes, that is the idea. BMitch solution might work too, but I like keeping container path managed with the script, rather than exposed and visible in a host cron setting.

Answer (score 2):

Cron runs your command with a shell, so the output redirect is handled by the shell running on your host, not inside your container. To get shell commands like this to run inside the container, you need to run a shell as your docker command, and escape or quote your any of those shell options to avoid having them interpreted until you are inside the container. E.g.

```
0 9 * * 1-5 sudo docker exec -i container_name /bin/sh -c \
  "/path/in/docker/container/script.sh > /path/in/docker/container/script.shout"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `bach -c` and put the redirect command between double quotes as in this command:

```
docker exec ${CONTAINER_ID} bash -c "./path/in/container/script.sh > /path/in/container/out"
```

- And we have to be sure `/path/in/container/script.sh` is an executable file either by using this command from the container:

```
chmod +x /path/in/container/script.sh
```

- or by using this command from the host machine:

```
docker exec ${CONTAINER_ID} chmod +x /path/in/container/script.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tee`: a program that reads stdin and writes the same to both stdout AND the file specified as an arg.

```
echo 'foo' | tee file.txt
```

will write the text 'foo' in file.txt

Your desired command becomes:

```
0 9 * * 1-5 sudo docker exec -i /path/in/docker/container/script.sh | tee /path/in/docker/container/script.shout
```

The drawback is that you also dump to stdout.
You may check [this SO question](https://superuser.com/questions/504343/alternative-to-the-tee-command-without-stdout) for further possibilities and workarounds.